# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'

Tags: c#

i am accepting a string and assigning that string to one of the indexes of array string. "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'" this is the error i am getting in following code. please give me a solution.

```
tmp = Console.ReadLine();
student_name[j] = tmp;
```

Comment: How do you declare student_name and tmp?

Comment: Can you provide full code?

Comment: when you get type errors like that, it's very important to show the actual types you've declared

Comment: Is `student_name` defined as a `string[][]`?

Comment: student_name is string array and tmp is simply string

Comment: Defenetly, change type of student name to string[]

Comment: Nah, we need the actual code you use to declare them.

Comment: actually student_name is a jagged array where length of row is fixed. i am taking input from user in string tmp and transferring that string to respective index of student_name array.

Comment: jagged array IS array of arrays! change it to simple string[]! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx or if you need that kind of sctructure (the name is first element, last name second, address is third and so on), then assign it properly: student_name[j][0] = tmp

Answer (score 3):

Either `tmp` is declared as a string array, or `student_name` is declared as `string[][]` (array of string arrays) or some other `IList<string[]>` or type with a string array indexed property. One of those things must be true for the code you posted to produce that error. Without more code to look at, this is as much info as we can give you.

Comment: Stop editing it every sec :) my finger cant click on "load edited" such rapidly

Comment: i have tried the list function but still it is not working